# Matlab, for loop does not initiate

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Tried to ask this at Matlab Central, and didn't get much replies. 
This is the code:

```
for
    ... creates "cent"
end

e = 5 ;
per = zeros(e,e)

for u = 1:e
    rsum = 0; 
    a = 0; 

    for p=1:e   
        u
        p 
        Xdiff = 0;
        Ydiff = 0;
        Zdiff = 0;

        Xdiff = (cent(u,1)-cent(:,1)).^2
        Ydiff = (cent(u,2)-cent(:,2)).^2
        Zdiff = (cent(u,3)-cent(:,3)).^2
        a = (Xdiff + Ydiff  + Zdiff).^0.5
        rsum = cent(u,6) + cent(:,6)  ;

        if a == rsum(p) 
            per(p,u) = p ; 
        else
            per(p,u) = 0 ; 
        end 

    end 
end
```

The script runs just fine, and I get no error messages. However, i get no display of u and p, and per is returned as a matrix with only zeros if i create it before the first for loop. If i create per as shown over, between the first and second, it is not created at all. I thus think that the code stops after the first loop. Why?

Comment: With `a == rsum(p)` you are checking for equality of floating point numbers, which rarely works the way you expect it to because of floating point errors. Thus, a matrix of all zeros is what you would get if the equality always fails.

You should use breakpoints [[link]](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to step through your code and confirm it's running the way you expect, examining the value of variables as they change.

Comment: Unable to see the output of u, p and {X/Y/Z}diff -->  nested p-loop is not run at all --> e < 1. However, previously you defined e = 5; Possibilities are 1. the code you post here is different from your local copy; 2. the description "get no display of u and p" is not accurate. Please verify. Also I would suggest you not use simple names such as "e" which also happens to be a pre-defined variable.

Comment: Hi!
I have tried putting a breakpoint in the second for loop, but nothing happens. I use the same e for both loops, and in the first loop, it is clear that i increase for each run, verified by writing "i" in the for loop. What I mean, is that in the second loop, it would write out the value of i and p, as I have wriiten in my code for each time it runs the loops. However, this does not happen. Finally, I told the loop to return 1 when a ==rsum is not true, but I still get  a zero matrix.

Comment: The whole code is too large to put here.

Comment: I have also figured out that the script stops entirely after the first for loop. It does not want to display cent outside the loop, and if i create a random new for loop after, it does not go into that either.

Comment: HURRAY!!!The issue was that break; should be used instead of return; in the if loop:D

Comment: @JonathanØklandTorstensen please either edit your question to include the original problem and answer yourself (yes, that's allowed) to show that you no longer need help, or, alternatively, you can delete this question if you think it holds no merit for the community. As your question is at 0 score and not closed this will not be penalised at this moment. Either option is a valid course of action according to SO policy, feel free to chose.